# Как образовано наречие "вприкуску"?

Tags: словообразование

В словообразовательном словаре (2010 год) Тихонова для этого наречия указано: прикуска — в-прикуск-у.

Это правильный разбор, в русском языке есть такое слово?

В словаре Ефремовой: прикуска (местн.) — закуска. Есть еще прикуска — вредная привычка лошади глотать воздух, хватаясь зубами за к.-н. предмет.
Но эти существительные вряд ли имеют отношение к наречию вприкуску, ведь
по смыслу вприкуску — это прикусывая.

Почему нельзя рассматривать такую схему: прикусывать — в-прикус-к-у?

Но здесь два суффикса. Можно ли в таких случаях считать, что это  сложный суффикс "ку"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же сами нашли слово *прикуска* в словаре, а теперь спрашиваете, есть ли такое слово. Есть, есть. И у Лопатина есть, и в "Русском словесном ударении" есть. А если есть, какие могут быть сомнения в образовании наречия *вприкуску*?

Comment: Спасибо. Это частный вопрос, таких наречий много. Поэтому мне хотелось бы узнать, верны ли следующие утверждения: 1) Существительное по значению не соответствует наречию, но это неважно. 2) Если такого существительного нет в словаре вообще, то это тоже неважно. 3) Можно считать, что образование наречия делается от абстрактной формы существительного, причем не имеет значения, есть ли такое конкретное слово в языке (в словаре)

Comment: @May пожалуйста, задавайте лишь _уточняющие_ вопросы в комментариях. Остальный вопросы оформляйте через «Задать вопрос».

Comment: Хорошо, но в данном случае вопросы как раз уточняют ответ, иначе я не могу его понять  Прикуска - редкое слово (спец. лексика),  по значению оно не относится к наречию.  Всё это неважно? Я об этом хотела спросить. Только третий вопрос вроде бы лишний и необязательный. Это как бы мое предположение, но я не уверена в нем. Вот это мне особенно интересно.

Comment: @Мау Вероятно, да. Слова "накладка" в нужном смысле нет вообще, да и "приглядка" сомнительна. Однако наречия существуют. Впрочем, возможно, что они образованы по аналогии.

Comment: Пр аналогии? Возможно, это как-то определяет ситуацию. Мне этот пример хочется сравнить с существительным труженик.  Слово  образуется по схеме: трудиться - (труженый) - труженик. Формы "труженый" формально не существует, но  она как бы используется  на промежуточном этапе, а суффикс выделяется сложный - "еник".  Возможно, здесь такая же ситуация. Спасибо  Вам еще раз за ответы.